# What is the easiest way to return server based error messages to a web based modal panel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dhtml

I've been tasked with adding a modal based UI feature to an internal application.  The quick summary is that I am posting a form via a modal panel, and I'm wondering the best way to cleanly provide feedback.

Firefox permits changing the page showing within the modal panel via a normal post, but IE opens it in a new window which seems to imply that a straight GET or POST won't work.  Is there any easy way around this?

I'm slightly hesitant to go the AJAX route because I've been told not to bring in any new javascript libraries, and I've never worked with PHP's CodeIgniter's support for it.  (I've done it via servlets and Richfaces A4J).  I don't think we are currently using AJAX for anything, although this might be the time to change that.

I'm open to any alternate suggestions, and I'll be looking into CodeIgniter's Ajax support in the meanwhile.

Comment: It's going to look really strange in a modal dialog if you refresh the entire page just to bring up the modal dialog again.

Comment: I agree ... I'm just going the ajax route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Easy" way around it, I think not.

Ajax is what you're looking for. Hopefully you're already using a js library since you can't bring any new one.